# Eliphaz HaTeimoni - who was he?

Tags: midrash, genealogy, job-iyov-book-of

In Seder HaDoros, it tells us that Bildad HaShuchi was one of the sons of Shuach ben Avraham Avinu. It also tells us that Elihu ben Barachel HaBuzi was son of Barachel ben Buz ben Nochor ben Terach. Who (genealogically) was Eliphaz HaTeimoni? Please cite any sources.

Comment: What about Tzofar Hanaamati?

Comment: @Heshy http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78438/zophar-hanaamosi-who-was-he

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [H'Ichud B'Chidud - Vol 57 - Vayeshev 5769](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50385&st=&pgnum=54&hilite=) and also in [Vol 95 - Ki Savo 5769](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50385&st=&pgnum=167) Eliphaz HaTeimoni is Eliphaz the son of Eisav.

> ואליפז התימני הוא אליפז בנו של עשו

Comment: Is there some connection to Vayeishev that I'm missing?

Comment: @Heshy: No you are not missing a connection to Vayeishev. This publication has questions each week with answers from the previous weeks questions.

Comment: Ah ok.  I thought maybe there was a connection because of that on top of @JoshuaPearl asking the question this week.